Storing output of a curl jq to environment variable in windows cmd
I want to save the output of curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test" ^| jq -r ".integrations.[0].id" to an environment variable within a jenkins batch command in Windows8 so that I can use it in subsequent commands.
How to do that?
I tried this but did not work.
@echo off ^
for /F "delims=" %%i in ("curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test" ^| jq -r ".integrations.[0].id"") do (set "response=%%i") ^
echo ID = %response% ^
endlocal


Try with @echo off && setlocal && for /F "delims=" %i in ('curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test" ^| jq -r ".integrations.[0].id"') do (set "response=%i") && call echo ID = %response% && endlocal if you want to call everything in one line from ther terminal. Or is this in a batch file?

The help file for the FOR command clearly shows the syntax of using single quotes to parse the output of a command. FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command Furthermore it shows that using double quotes means you are parsing a string. FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command

Perhaps something along the lines of env.Response = bat(script:""" curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test" | jq -r ".integrations.[0].id" """, returnStdout: true).trim(), would allow you to use $Response elsewhere.

The following worked for me:
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`echo xyz`) do (set response=%%i)
echo "ID = %response%"

The things I did differently:

Enabled the back quote option
Put the command within back quotes
Use "echo "xyz" instead of curl piped into jq.


The below worked. Just put the curl in ''
@echo off ^
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test" ^| jq -r ".integrations.[0].id"') do (set "response=%%i") ^
echo ID = %response% ^

endlocal

Hey Rahul! Great contribution, when posting solutions it's always helpful to add a brief explanation of why it works, and what you changed. Keep 'em coming!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
